# How to refactor multiple switch statments

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I've got a rest endpoint where based on Enum value I call method of specific service. All services extends after the same abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseService{
  someMethod()
}
```

```
public class ServiceA extends BaseService{
  @Override
  someMethod()
}
```

```
public class ServiceB extends BaseService{
  @Override
  someMethod()
}
```

```
public class RestEndpoint {
  @Inject
  ServiceA serviceA
  @Inject
  ServiceB serviceB

  public void someEndpoint(Enum value){
    switch (value){
    case 1:
       serviceA.someMethod();
    case 2:
       serviceB.someMethod();
   }
  }
}
```

The thing is, there might be a lot more services, and I wonder if there is some better way of doing it. I thought about implementing strategy pattern, but I don't know if that wouldn't be 'overkill' since there will be at most ~10/15 services.

EDIT

So because my services were beans, that injected other beans inside, there wasn't any 'easy' way to refactor this - I couldn't create some method in Enum class that would for example `return new ServiceA()` because then beans inside my `ServiceA` instance wouldn't be injected. I could try to get context, and set specific bean, but then it wouldn't be safe (for example u could try to inject non-bean, and compilator wouldn't let you know about it).

So if my `BaseService` implementation wouldn't use other beans, the easiest way was to create method in Enum class

```
public abstract BaseService getService();
```

and implement this like

```
anyServiceA{
 @Override
 public BaseService getService(){
  return new ServiceA();
 }
}
```

and in Rest service just call `value.getService().someMethod();`

Maybe it'll help someone.

Comment: the only real problem in your logic is that you forget your break statements.

Comment: *BTW*: `case <int>` won't fly with `value` being an `Enum`...

Comment: It was just a code sample, I know about breaks and that case <int> wouldn't work, but thank tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally , There are 7 ways to refactor switch statement are available (Could be more than that :)).

```
1) Implementing the Strategy Pattern via Java Enum
2) Implementing the Command Pattern
3) Using the Java 8+ Supplier
4) Defining a Custom Functional Interface
5) Relying on Abstract Factory
6) Implementing State Pattern
7) Implementing via Predicate
```

You can refer this link for implementation

https://www.developer.com/java/data/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements.html

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Must read:[refactoring switch statement well explained](https://refactoring.guru/smells/switch-statements)